# Display item of instance

Tags: asp.net, instance

I have made an instance of the type competition by retrieving data from my database. 
The function selectCompetitionById return one row of data.

```
Competition competition = BLLc.selectCompetitionById(competitionId);
```

How can I display item of this instance on my page? (Repeater doesn't work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create an auto-generated form, then you could use a [`DetailsView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.aspx):

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="competitionDetails" RunAt="Server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" />
```

Create a dummy array (with just the one item) as the data source:

```
competitionDetails.DataSource = new Competition[] { competition };
```

---

The other way is to use standard HTML template that references your object.  Make it a property of the page first:

```
<script runat="Server">
    public Competition competition { get; set; }

    void Page_Load()
    {
        competition = BLLc.selectCompetitionById(competitionId);;
        this.DataBind();
    }
</script>
```

Then reference it in markup as needed:

```
<div>
    <span>Title</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span><%# competition.Title %></span>
</div>
<div> etc ... </div>
```